# R: Error in get_map() from ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to plot a simple map in R using function get_map() for a certain location. Following is my code :

e.g.

```
get_map(location = "texas", zoom = 10, source = "google")
```

I've tried different parameters. The error I'm getting is following:

```
Error in aperm.default(map, c(2, 1, 3)) : 
perm' is of wrong length 3 (!= 2)
```

What is exactly happening in the background & how do I fix it? I checked all the possible blogs I could, no one seems to get this error.

Please help!

Comment: I get a map of the area with no problem. Please add anything else that might be relevant, like what version you're using. Also, seems silly, but I often solve weird problems by just restarting my R session

Comment: I am using R version 3.5.0. I 've updated the ggplot2 & ggmap packages. I tried restarting R but getting the same error. For now, I've used a different function to plot map but don't know why get_map or get_googlemap (functions from the ggmap package) are giving the same error

Comment: I ran your code with no problem, either. But since the error message is associated with `get_googlemap()` function, you can try entering `debug(get_googlemap)` in your console & re-run your code. This steps through the function & allows you to check where things went wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I checked with debugging and I am getting a static map of matrix 1X1. Hence the function aperm() which is trying to transform matrix is giving the error. I check the URL on the browser and get a black screen with 1 dot (I guess that is what it is returning, a 1x1 matrix)

Comment: It looks like the base_url in `get_googlemap()` not correct. It is not secure. If I use `https` and check in a browser, I see the map. With `http` it gives a black screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs due to the base url. In `CRAN version` , the base url is not secure.
Use dev version of this package from {github} instead & function runs fine.
Use `devtools::install_github(""dkahle/ggmap")` to install library from github

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and updating my google api key worked out.

Comment: You are not answering the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate directly to the URL generated, and you should see a different error message that might be more informative:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=31,-97&zoom=10&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&key=<INSERT_YOUR_KEY>
```

In my case, it said my API key was not valid for this API, although up to that point the error just said the same thing about

```
Error in aperm.default(map, c(2, 1, 3)) : 
     invalid first argument, must be an array
```

and

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
```